# javascript - Pass Event and Parameters to function called with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, parameter-passing, addeventlistener

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", eventkeyup(event, something), false);

    function eventkeyup(event, something) {

    //could not be able to get the event object here.

}
```

How can I access Event in this function ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass function itself, not return value of it which is `undefined` in your case.

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", eventkeyup(something), false);

function eventkeyup(something) {
    return function(event){
       // you have event and something here
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to achieve this 
const value1 = 'string1';
const value2 = 'string2';
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click',valid(e,value1));
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click',valid(e,value2));

function valid(e,value){
//do the logic here but logic depends on the value and event
}

Comment: I want to send event and parameters both to the function

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a function while you use it inside `addEventListener`. You can only pass the reference of that particular function. For your desired situation you can define a function inside the `addEventListener` and in that function just call your desired function and pass the event and some other variable as arguments.

Check if this helps:

```js
let div = document.getElementById("demo");
let someText = "hello\n World\n how are you doing ? ";
div.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  eventkeyup(event, someText);
})

function eventkeyup(event, something) {
  console.log(something);
  console.log(event);
}
```

```css
#demo {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  /*border: 1px solid dodgerblue;*/
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  text-align: justified;
}
```

```html
<p>click on the below div and wait for sometimes</p>
<p> in the console if you only see the event object scroll up</p>
<div id="demo">
  <div>
```